# Avoiding NAs in as.numeric()

Tags: r, na

If I did this, I get correct result:

```
a <- c("10","28","3")
which(as.numeric(a) == min(as.numeric(a)))
[1] 3
```

But if there is NAs in the vector, then there is a problem

```
a <- c("10","28","3","NA")
which(as.numeric(a) == min(as.numeric(a)))
integer(0)
Warning messages:
1: In which(as.numeric(a) == min(as.numeric(a))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In which(as.numeric(a) == min(as.numeric(a))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: There is no need for R in the title, given that you have it tagged as r

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two things.

First, there's a difference between the character string `"NA"` and the R data representation for missing values, `NA`. Remove the quotes around NA in your example to see:

```
a <- c("10","28","3",NA)
```

Second, when you're using `min` with *actual* missing values (i.e. not the character strings `"NA"`) you'll want to use `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
which(as.numeric(a) == min(as.numeric(a),na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You are right about pointing out the "NA". It is a typo. It is meant to be a NA for missing values. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: You might also want to use `which.min`

Answer (score 8):

Your main problem is not specifying `na.rm = TRUE` within the call to `min`

```
numeric_a <- as.numeric(a)

which(numeric_a == min(numeric_a, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 3
```

Or you can use the `which.min` which does not require you to specify that the NA values should be removed. This will only give you the first match, not all matches (Thanks  @Dason for reminding me to clarify this)

```
which.min(numeric_a)
```

Comment: But if you use `which.min` just note that you'll only get a single result even if there are multiple values that match the minimum value.

Comment: mnel and Dason, thank you both guys for further illustrations on the solution.